# Property tax in NYC

Tags: united-states, tax-law

How much do property taxes amount to in terms of their related asset worth in NYC?

Are they delivered in form of bill or notifies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New York City has webpages that [list the property tax rates](https://www1.nyc.gov/site/finance/taxes/property-tax-rates.page) and [explain how to calculate property tax](https://www1.nyc.gov/site/finance/taxes/calculating-your-property-taxes.page).  It's pretty complicated, but at its root it depends on an estimate of the property's market value.  There are law firms that specialize in appealing property valuations in return for a percentage of the reduction in the tax bill.

Property owners receive bills from the city.  More information is available at the city's page on [property tax bills and payments](https://www1.nyc.gov/site/finance/taxes/property-bills-and-payments.page).